# Data sync between Amplify Data Store, App Sync and Mobile App

Tags: flutter, graphql, aws-amplify, serverless, aws-appsync

When we use an Amplify Datastore, we have several ways to access the data. I  uses three of them:

1. Lambda function invokes App Sync API to create a new "Post" mutation
2. The Mobile app (Flutter) invokes the Datastore.save() method
3. I manually create/monitor data on the Amplify console.

I can see the data is in sync between the Amplify console and mobile app. Create/Delete propagate correctly.

However, when I create record with Lambda Function, using App Sync API, I need to refresh the mobile app as well as the Amplify console. I understand that directly adding records to dynamodb table will not work. However, as per the documentation, a mutation using app sync should be propagated to the clients.

Does this require any additional configuration? How do I implement this usecase of lambda function creating data to be displayed real-time on the mobile app? The sync is perfect between the Amplify Console and mobile app, so I believe the problem is within my AWS configuration and not the Flutter code.

Lambda Function that uses App Sync to create records:

```
/* Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT
    API_ANANTA_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT
    API_ANANTA_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT
    API_ANANTA_GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT
    ENV
    REGION
Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT */

import { default as fetch, Request } from "node-fetch";

const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = process.env.API_ANANTA_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT;
const GRAPHQL_API_KEY = process.env.API_ANANTA_GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT;

const query = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CREATE_POST($input: CreatePostInput!) {
    createPost(input: $input) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
 */
export const handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

  const variables = {
    input: {
      title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    },
  };

  /** @type {import('node-fetch').RequestInit} */
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "x-api-key": GRAPHQL_API_KEY,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
  };

  const request = new Request(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, options);

  let statusCode = 200;
  let body;
  let response;

  try {
    response = await fetch(request);
    body = await response.json();
    if (body.errors) statusCode = 400;
  } catch (error) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = {
      errors: [
        {
          status: response.status,
          message: error.message,
          stack: error.stack,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  };
};
```

Flutter code that displays data:

```
              Expanded(
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Post>>(
                  stream: Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery(
                    Post.classType,
                  ),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      final posts = snapshot.data!.items;
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: posts.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final post = posts[index];
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(post.title),
                            subtitle: Text(post.description),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                  },
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue before. I solved this problem by adding updatedAT, createdAt, _lastChangedAt, and _version to the query output.

```html
const query = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CREATE_POST($input: CreatePostInput!) {
    createPost(input: $input) {
      id
      updatedAt
      createdAt
      _lastChangedAt
      _version
    }
  }
`;
```